# How to make custom jquery method accessible from Drupal.behaviors, across multiple javascript files?

Tags: 7, views, theming, javascript

I have a custom views plugin.  When the view is displayed, the javascript below gets loaded.  Note the custom method, `do_stuff`, which gets called from within `Drupal.behaviors`.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.do_stuff(indx){
    alert (indx);
  }
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings.hasOwnProperty('mymodule')) {
        $('.my-item').each(function(indx, item) {
          // do stuff to each item
          $(this).do_stuff(indx);
        });
      }
    }
  } 
}(jQuery));
```

I would now like to create a second plugin, which loads a second javascript file.  This second javascript file needs access to the custom method, `do_stuff`.  Is there a way I could access the `do_stuff` code defined in the first javascript file, from within the second javascript file?  For example, is there a way to move the custom method inside Drupal.behaviors, so that it could then be accessed from within any other javascript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a slightly different JS pattern with Drupal, which is based on the [Javascript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

```
var FOO = (function(me, $, Drupal, undefined) {
  me.name = "FOO";

  function do_something_awesome () {
  }

  me.do_stuff = function do_stuff () {
  }

  function init (context, settings) {
    me.do_stuff();
    do_something_awesome();
  };

  Drupal.behaviors[me.name] = {
    attach: init
  };

  return me;
}(FOO || {}, jQuery, Drupal));
```

Anything directly attached to `me` will be public on the `FOO`.  The rest is private.  Typically, I will pass in `FOO` into the closure in dependent libraries.

Comment: One thing I do not understand:  Why did you include 'undefined' as one of the input variables?

Comment: @user606696  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602901/what-is-the-purpose-of-passing-in-undefined